# Disabling Kendo Mobile Switch in Javascript or HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, icenium

We are using the Telerik Kendo mobile suite for developing a hybrid application for iOS and Android.

Has anyone had any experience with using the [Switch component](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/switch) from this suite?  I've checked [the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/switch) and there doesn't seem to be a way to disable this component at all?

Does anyone know if there is in fact, a way to disable this component?

As a reference, this code definitely does NOT disable it.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-role="switch" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to the kendo team, it is not supported.   http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/switch/disable-switch.aspx

Comment: Thanks @giltnerj0, you should make this an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI Developer here - we are going to support this with our next release (Q3 2013).